# I need to create a simple notification in my java GUI

Tags: java

How to use `org-openide-awt` jar file for creating notification on `java` GUI.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    NotificationDisplayer.getDefault().notify("Title 1", icon, "Text 1", new DemoActionListener(), NotificationDisplayer.Priority.HIGH);
}
```

I try this.But didn't work.

Comment: Java what? AWT, Swing, JavaFX? How do we know what you are doing based on a single line of code? If using Swing then I would just use a `JOptionPane`. Read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) for working examples.

Comment: Java Swing.I want NotificationDisplayer

Comment: Please help me to do this

Comment: I want to show notification on my GUI like facebook notification

Comment: are you getting any exceptions? if yes, post stacktrace

Comment: I didn't understand how to create notification on jframe

Comment: you could use a `jdialog` instead, since you are using swing already